# Unable to connect to EM, even though the Listern, dbconsole and DB are all running

Tags: database, oracle11g, oracle-enterprise-linux

I installed Oracle 11g on OEL5 yesterday and was able to access it EM (https://localhost.localdomain:1158/em). However, when tried connecting today it was unable to connect.

I can connect to db vis sqlplus and verified that that Listener and dbconsole is running. I shutdown and started the DB, dbaconsole and Listerner multiple times but still unable to access EM (https://localhost.localdomain:1158/em). Also, done this after rebotting the machine but still the same issue.

I checked the following log files which have warnings and errors:

***emdctl.trc***

```
2013-04-01 14:00:27,196 Thread-3348649696 WARN  http: nmehl_connect_internal: connect failed to (localhost.localdomain:1830)
: Connection refused (error = 111)
2013-04-01 14:00:27,196 Thread-3348649696 ERROR main: nmectla_agentctl: Error connecting to http://localhost.localdomain:183
0/emd/main. Returning status code 1
2013-04-01 15:52:32,626 Thread-3858654944 WARN  http: nmehl_connect_internal: connect failed to (localhost.localdomain:5500)
: Connection refused (error = 111)
2013-04-01 16:01:08,737 Thread-2888275680 WARN  http: nmehl_connect_internal: connect failed to (localhost.localdomain:5500)
: Connection refused (error = 111)
```

***emagent.log***

```
2013-04-01 12:34:33,620 Thread-4251236064 Starting Agent 10.2.0.4.4 from /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1 (00701)
2013-04-01 12:34:34,403 Thread-4251236064 Undefined column name __intervalONNECT_DATA in expression ((gc_cr_recv < _gc_cr_re
cv) ? 0 : (gc_cr_recv - _gc_cr_recv))/__intervalONNECT_DATA=(SID=%SID%)))
             (00104)
2013-04-01 12:34:34,403 Thread-4251236064 Undefined column name __intervalCT_DATA in expression ((gc_cur_recv < _gc_cur_recv
) ? 0 : (gc_cur_recv - _gc_cur_recv))/__intervalCT_DATA=(SID=%SID%)))
             (00104)
```

***emagent.trc***

```
2013-04-02 00:18:35,273 Thread-1468947040 ERROR recvlets: Error setting threshold for metric file, target orcl.localdomain o
racle_database
2013-04-02 00:18:35,273 Thread-1468947040 ERROR recvlets: Tried to set threshold on metric file, target orcl.localdomain ora
cle_database,                   for uninitialized recvlet AQMetrics
2013-04-02 00:18:35,273 Thread-1468947040 ERROR recvlets: Error setting threshold for metric file, target orcl.localdomain o
racle_database
2013-04-02 00:18:35,273 Thread-1468947040 ERROR recvlets: Tried to set threshold on metric service, target orcl.localdomain
oracle_database,                   for uninitialized recvlet AQMetrics
2013-04-02 00:18:35,273 Thread-1468947040 ERROR recvlets: Error setting threshold for metric service, target orcl.localdomai
n oracle_database
2013-04-02 00:18:35,273 Thread-1468947040 ERROR recvlets: Tried to set threshold on metric service, target orcl.localdomain
oracle_database,                   for uninitialized recvlet AQMetrics
2013-04-02 00:18:35,273 Thread-1468947040 ERROR recvlets: Error setting threshold for metric service, target orcl.localdomai
n oracle_database
2013-04-02 00:18:35,273 Thread-1468947040 WARN  upload: Upload manager has no Failure script: disabled
2013-04-02 00:18:35,273 Thread-1468947040 WARN  upload: Amount of upload data will be recalculated due to reload.enabling co
llections and regenerating metadata.
2013-04-02 00:18:35,273 Thread-1468947040 WARN  TargetManager: Regenerating all Metadata
2013-04-02 00:18:35,286 Thread-1466931808 ERROR pingManager: nmepm_pingReposURL: Did not receive a response header from repo
sitory
2013-04-02 00:18:35,298 Thread-1466931808 ERROR pingManager: nmepm_pingReposURL: Did not receive a response header from repo
sitory
2013-04-02 00:18:35,332 Thread-1468947040 WARN  upload: Truncating value of "SHORT_NAME" from "Average Synchronous Single-Block Read Latency (ms)" to "Average Synchronous Single-Block Read La"
2013-04-02 00:18:35,332 Thread-1468947040 WARN  upload: Truncating value of "SHORT_NAME" from "Average Synchronous Single-Block Read Latency (ms)" to "Average Synchronous Single-Block Read La"
2013-04-02 00:18:35,414 Thread-1468947040 WARN  upload: Truncating value of "COLUMN_LABEL" from "Total messages processed per queue per subscriber per minute in the last interval" to "Total messages processed per queue per subscriber per minute in "
2013-04-02 00:18:35,414 Thread-1468947040 WARN  upload: Truncating value of "COLUMN_LABEL" from "Total messages received per queue per subscriber per minute in the last interval" to "Total messages received per queue per subscriber per minute in t"
2013-04-02 00:18:35,414 Thread-1468947040 WARN  upload: Truncating value of "COLUMN_LABEL" from "Messages processed per queue (%) per subscriber per minute in the last interval" to "Messages processed per queue (%) per subscriber per minute in th"
2013-04-02 00:18:35,414 Thread-1468947040 WARN  upload: Truncating value of "COLUMN_LABEL" from "Age of the first message in persistent queue per subscriber (seconds)" to "Age of the first message in persistent queue per subscriber (sec"
2013-04-02 00:18:35,415 Thread-1468947040 WARN  upload: Truncating value of "COLUMN_LABEL" from "Age of the first message in the buffered queue per queue (seconds)" to "Age of the first message in the buffered queue per queue (second"
2013-04-02 00:18:35,427 Thread-1468947040 WARN  collector: enable collector
2013-04-02 00:18:35,429 Thread-1468947040 WARN  collector: the column name first_message_age in this condition does not exist in metric aq_msgs_persistentq_per_subscriber
2013-04-02 00:18:35,432 Thread-1468947040 WARN  collector: the column name first_message_age in this condition does not exist in metric aq_msgs_persistentq_per_subscriber
2013-04-02 00:18:35,415 Thread-1468947040 WARN  upload: Truncating value of "COLUMN_LABEL" from "Age of the first message in
 the buffered queue per queue (seconds)" to "Age of the first message in the buffered queue per queue (second"
2013-04-02 00:18:35,427 Thread-1468947040 WARN  collector: enable collector
2013-04-02 00:18:35,429 Thread-1468947040 WARN  collector: the column name first_message_age in this condition does not exis
t in metric aq_msgs_persistentq_per_subscriber
2013-04-02 00:18:35,432 Thread-1468947040 WARN  collector: the column name first_message_age in this condition does not exis
t in metric aq_msgs_persistentq_per_subscriber
2013-04-02 00:18:35,435 Thread-1468947040 WARN  collector: Regenerating all DefaultColls
2013-04-02 00:18:36,505 Thread-1466931808 ERROR upload: Exceeded max. amount of upload data: 312 files, 45.885256 MB Data. 3
9.01% of disk used. Disabling collections.
2013-04-02 00:18:36,505 Thread-1466931808 WARN  collector: Disable collector
2013-04-02 00:19:05,550 Thread-1468947040 ERROR pingManager: nmepm_pingReposURL: Did not receive a response header from repo
sitory
2013-04-02 00:19:05,561 Thread-1468947040 ERROR pingManager: nmepm_pingReposURL: Did not receive a response header from repository
2013-04-02 00:19:35,939 Thread-1468947040 ERROR pingManager: nmepm_pingReposURL: Did not receive a response header from repository
2013-04-02 00:19:36,060 Thread-1468947040 ERROR pingManager: nmepm_pingReposURL: Did not receive a response header from repository
```

I have spent the last two days checking online but haven't been able to resolve this issue. it maybe an issue with localho greatly appreciate any help/suggestions and if you could provide easy to follow instructions, as I'm new to Linux and Oracle 11g.

Many thanks in advance.st.localdomain but I'm not sure how to check or update this.

I would greatly appreciate any help/suggestions and if you could provide easy to follow instructions, as I'm new to Linux and Oracle 11g.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the IP Address along with Hostname in the /etc/hosts file and restart dbconsole, Issue would be resolved.

Thanks 
Anil